# NFT Collections and Supply - ERC721 vs ERC 1155

Tags: solidity

I'm building an NFT marketplace, say a copycat of OpenSea.

I need to make my users able to mint their own tokens. That's ok, that would be an ERC721 contract. But I want to allow my users to mint different collections (as OpenSea does) with different supplies as follows:

- (1) Have a single collection
- (2) Have multiple collections
- (A) Mint 1/1 NFTs
- (B) Mint 1/N NFTs (say, for instance, 100 in total of the same NFT)

That makes a set of combinations:

- Single collections (1) of 1/1 NFTs (A)
- Single collections (1) of 1/N NFTs (B)
- Multiple collections (2) of 1/1 NFTs (A)
- Multiple collections (2) of 1/N NFTs (B)
- Single or multiple collections (1 or 2) of both 1/1 and 1/N NFTS (A and B)

When using ERC721 I would be able to make (A) and (B), yet for every collection I would have to deploy a new contract. I want to avoid this.

Is this covered by ERC1155?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (A) Mint 1/1 NFTs
>
> (B) Mint 1/N NFTs (say, for instance, 100 in total of the same NFT)

Both options are in accordance with the [ERC-1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155) standard.

The ERC-1155 defines a collection of tokens, where each token has an ID and an amount (specified as a `value` in the standard). Which means, you can have for example:

- Token ID 1 that has amount of 1. At any point in time, it's always owned by just one address. (Case A)
- Token ID 2 that has amount of 10. Five of these tokens ID 2 is owned by Alice, and other five tokens ID 2 is owned by Bob. (Case B)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Petr, very clear! Just a doubt: in Case B, the 10 tokens 10 need to have a sub-ID, because they can't all have the same ID 2, right? I mean, if you buy the NFT #10 of a collection with 100 supply, you're buying ID 10, not a copy of ID 1 of that collection

Comment: @JacquesGodin They don't have a sub-ID. The ERC-1155 is in fact a combination of the non-fungible (ERC-721) and fungible (ERC-20) token approach. So in the example from the answer, there are 10 fungible copies of the non-fungible token ID 2.